# Does mysql works if mysqli is enabled but mysql is disabled and viceversa in a server?

Tags: php, mysql, apache, mysqli

I wanted to know the below cases:

Case1: In a server mysql is enabled. But mysqli disabled.

Qs: Will php mysql methods work?

Case2: In a server mysqli is enabled. But mysql disabled.

Qs: Will php mysqli methods work?

Please answer with yes/no first then try to give the explanation.

In my client's server mysqli is enabled but mysql is disabled. But php mysql methods are working.

Comment: The fact that `mysql_*` functions are removed in PHP 7+ should have rendered this question moot.

Comment: what if the php version is below 7 ?

Comment: Look, just pretend that `mysql_*` never existed. Don't play games with security.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. No
2. Yes

> In fact, the “i” in mysqli stands for “improved”. mysqli was developed
>   to take advantage of the new features available in MySQL since version
>   4.1.3.  Also, you can use it since PHP 5. So, if you code with PHP5 with a newer version  of MySQL, it's strongly recommended for you to
>   use the extension “mysqli” over  “mysql”.Feb 13, 2014 (post over
>   google)
>            Documentation link :http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.overview.php Pl. refer in detail

As per your case in client, server mysqli is enabled so all mysql as well as mysqli extension method work.

Comment: Why should the mysql_* functions not work when I deinstall the mysqli package?

Comment: Hi Keyur Buch : Thanks for your informative response. Referring to the comment of Mr 'apokryfos' in above, do you still stick with your answer with PHP version 7?

Comment: In php7 the mysql_-extension is removed, so there wouldn't even be a reason to ask this question...

Answer (score -1):

1. yes
2. yes

The apis are independent from each other. In php 7 mysql_* was removed, mysqli is still usable.

> In my client's server mysqli is enabled but mysql is disabled. But php mysql methods are working.

No contradiction here. This just means mysql_* was not properly disabled.